# Почему игнорируется имя атрибута при передаче данных в компоненту?

Tags: reactjs

Вот родительская компонента:

```
const Profile = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyPosts state={props.postsData}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Вот дочерняя:

```
const MyPosts = (props) => {
    let posts = props.postsData.map(p => <Post msg={p.msg} likeCount={p.likeCount}/>);

    return /* тут код */;
}
```

Чего-то я не пойму. Я передаю в компоненту MyPosts состояние через атрибут **state**. Насколько я понимаю, теперь в компоненте MyPosts я должен обращаться к props следующим образом: `props.state`, но почему-то срабатывает и `props.postsData`.

Это так происходит, потому что я только один объект передаю? Или почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так Вы передаёте пропсу `state`, а внутри хотите использовать пропсу `postsData`, которой вообще нет у компонента.

```
const MyPosts = (props) => {
    let posts = props.state.map(p => <Post msg={p.msg} likeCount={p.likeCount}/>);

    return /* тут код */;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос немного другой, но он решает мою проблему. Я просто запутался с этими джейсонами)